# Permitir acceso a archivos solo bajo ciertos dominios con htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

Tengo un servidor en el cual deseo que archivos de video con extensión mkv solo puedan ser accesados desde 2 únicos dominios.

Dominio 1: El mismo donde esta alojado el contenido (video.midominio.com)
Dominio 2: Otro dominio externo (cliente.midominio.com)

Intente con HREFERRER el problema es que en el dominio 1 únicamente uso un pequeño index para que liste los archivos en el directorio y si daba clic al archivo me lanzaba en automático un 403 Forbidden

EL que tenía era este:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(video\.)?midominio\.com [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(cliente\.)?midominio\.com
RewriteRule \.(mkv)$ - [F,L]
Options -Indexes
```

Que opción me pueden recomendar para lograr lo que necesito.

Comment: ¿Tienes un VirtualHost para cada dominio?